# Send Json String data to Server

Tags: android, json

```
 String Person_Name=et1.getText().toString();
 String Mobile_Number=et2.getText().toString();
 String Person_Query=et3.getText().toString();
 String Action=et4.getText().toString();

try
{
    JSONObject action=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject user=new JSONObject();
    action.put("person_name", Person_Name);
    action.put("mobile_number", Mobile_Number);
    action.put("person_query", Person_Query);
    action.put("action", Action);
    user.put("result",action);


     jsonString1 =user.toString();
}
catch (Exception je)
{

}
```

Here I am Collecting my all data and store in json String now I want to send Json String to server How Could I do This Please suggest me.

Comment: you need HTTPRequest methods for sending Data that have following methods GET, POST,PUT, DELETE In Your case you either need POST or PUT methods

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(wurl);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
httppostreq.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
```

Dont forget to give **internet permission** in Android Manifest file

Detailed Tutorial : http://osamashabrez.com/client-server-communication-android-json/

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method for Gingerbread and up [according to Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) is to use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (instead of `DefaultHttpClient`).

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/api/whatever");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Outputs (sending)
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");

    DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    printout.write(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));

    printout.flush();
    printout.close();
```

Where `json` is your json object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your link");
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(user.toString()); 
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
httppost.setEntity(se); 

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void postData() {
   // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it Depends how your server side is implemented
Normally sending data Requires Either HTTPPost Method or HTTPPut methods. More commonly used is HTTPPost methods That has header data and Body Data

you need to do it in following way

1- convert your json object to String

```
user.toString();
```

2- add Targeted URL

```
String URL="Enter URL here";
```

3- add url to the request

```
response = dohttpPostWithCode(URL.toString(),user.toString());
```

response is String [ ] that have 2 index 
i- for response code
ii- for data

4- method to handle data

```
     public String[] dohttpPostWithCode(String url,String postParameters ) throws Exception {
         URL weburl = new URL(url);
         URI uri = new URI(weburl.getProtocol(), weburl.getUserInfo(), weburl.getHost(), weburl.getPort(), weburl.getPath(), weburl.getQuery(), weburl.getRef());
            BufferedReader in = null;
            String[] result = new String[2];         
            try {
                 HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                int timeoutConnection = 20000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                int timeoutSocket = 20000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
                HttpURLConnection httpURL=(HttpURLConnection) weburl.openConnection();
                httpURL.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURL.setDoInput(true);
                httpURL.setRequestMethod("POST");
                HttpClient client =new  DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);            
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
                //httpPost.addHeader("language","en");
                httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type",  "application/json");

               // StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(postParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postParameters));
               // httpPost.setEntity(entity);
               // httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);               
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }
                in.close();
/*              String result = sb.toString();
                return result;*/
                result[0] = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"";
                result[1] = sb.toString();
                return result;
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now its completed

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use JSONStringer class and send the data with key and value pair.

```
 HttpPost request = new HttpPost(your URL);
 request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

 JSONStringer vm;
 try {
        vm = new JSONStringer().object().key("person_name").value(Person_Name)
        .key("mobile_number").value(Mobile_Number)
        .key("person_query").value(Person_Query)
        .key("action").value(Action).endObject();
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(vm.toString());
        request.setEntity(entity);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help u, to post data to sever and get result from server -

```
// Sending HTTPs Requet to Server

    try {
        Log.v("GG", "Sending sever 1 - try");
        // start - line is for sever connection/communication
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "10.0.0.1/abc.php");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qrcode", contents));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // end - line is for sever connection/communication
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Send to server and inserted into mysql Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response= httpclient.execute(httppost);

        entity = response.getEntity();
        String getResult = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.e("response =", " " + getResult);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "
                + e.toString());
    }
```